# html stored in a field gets split to multiple rows

Tags: html, xml, hive, parquet

I have a hive table holding parquet files. The rows either hold an html page or a simple string.  When I try a simple select

```
select text from table
```

I get the entire html as a single row.

```
1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/
```

[image]

But when I apply any filter

```
select text from table where text rlike 'xml';
```

every tag in the html is shown as a separate row. Like this

```
1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
3       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
4   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Why does it happen?

**Edit**

I thought it has something to do with new line character, but in this case the first select should return the same result as the second which doesn't happen.

Also. [This](https://www.marcel.is/how-newline-can-ruin-your-hive/) article says it shouldn't be a problem for parquet anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it actually were new lines. After replacing them

```
regexp_replace(text, '\n', '') as text
```

I can work with the html as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

rlike is based on regular expression.

[Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators):
**A RLIKE B
NULL if A or B is NULL, TRUE if any (possibly empty) substring of A matches the Java regular expression B, otherwise FALSE. For example, 'foobar' RLIKE 'foo' evaluates to TRUE and so does 'foobar' RLIKE '^f.*r$'.**

So the statement `select text from table where text rlike 'xml';` will most likely retrieve all **substrings** of text that has characters 'x','m','l',while treating the space between the tags as the delimiter.

```
select text from table where text like '%xml%'
```